# Best way to stream MP3 from an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio-streaming

I am working on an application that will stream music from a server of mine from an iPhone application.

This is my first iPhone app so I am a bit confused :

1. What would be the best way to do
   this?
2. Is there something already built in
   that I could use, like a MP3 player
   that I just need to point toward the
   correct server?
3. Do I need a streaming server to do
   so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm relatively new to Objective-C/Cocoa (touch), but I have read an article on the cocoawithlove site titled "Streaming and playing an MP3 stream" and tested the sample code on my iPhone and it works perfectly. I don't know about the licensing or anything, if you would be able to use it, but I'm sure someone or even you can figure that out.

Sorry again for not being able to provide any more information or even a link. This is my first answer on SO and cannot post hyperlinks :(

(edit: Here's the link: [Streaming and playing an MP3 stream](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html))

Comment: How complicated was it to get it to run on your iphone?

Comment: It just did? You do have a developer license right? Set up your device and then when you build it make sure to choose device and not simulator.