# how can i download from apps store through xcode

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to link to the iTunes store from iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893604/how-to-link-to-the-itunes-store-from-iphone-app)

hai! everyone can any one tell me about sample code for downloading from apps store.
Pls some one help me.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please be more detailed. You're probably trying to either do something with in-app purchases, or open app store links (itms://). I can't tell.

Comment: yes i in my project try to do app purchase