# Opening iTunes Store to specific song

Tags: iphone, objective-c, itunes-store

Ok, I have seen similar questions here but none are actually answering the problem for me.

I have a streaming audio app and the stream source returns to me the song title and artist name. I have an iTunes button in the app, and want to open the iTunes STORE (search) to that exact song, or at least close.  I have tried the following:

---

```
NSString *baseString = @"itms://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/advancedSearchResults?songTerm=";

NSString *str1 = [self.songTitle2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

NSString *str2 = [self.artist2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@&artistTerm=%@", baseString, str1, str2];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

---

This call does indeed switch me to the iTunes STORE as expected, but then it pops up an error "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". I am obviously on-line as the song is actively streaming, and I am in the store. The search box in iTunes app only shows the song name and nothing else.

Here is an example of a generated string:
itms://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/advancedSearchResults?artistTerm=Veruca+Salt&artistTerm=Volcano+Girls

I have tired taking the string it generates and pasting it into Safari, and it works OK on my Mac, opening to albums from the artist in the store. Why not on the phone?

Also, it seems to ignore both items, as it does not take me to the song by that artist. Does this require also knowing the album name (which I do not have at this time.)

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I was not sure how to do that!  :-)

Comment: edited the title to mention the store

Comment: Oh, my bad. I want it to open the iTunes STORE, not iTunes itself. Thanks for editing that Daj-Djan. I will edit the question as well.

Comment: The example you're using does not use songTerm. Instead uses artistTerm twice.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I am answering my own question.

After much digging and a talk with one of the best programmers I know, we have a solution, so I thought I would share it here. This solution takes the song name and artist, actually does make a call to the Link Maker API, gets back an XML document, and extracts the necessary info to create a link to the iTunes Store, opening the store to the song in an album by that artist that contains the song.

In the interface of the view controller, add:

```
@property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) NSOperationQueue* operationQueue;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL searching;
```

In the implementation:

```
@synthesize operationQueue = _operationQueue;
@synthesize searching = _searching;
```

Here are the methods and code that will do this for you:

```
// start an operation Queue if not started
-(NSOperationQueue*)operationQueue
{
    if(_operationQueue == nil) {
        _operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    }
    return _operationQueue;
}
// change searching state, and modify button and wait indicator (if you wish)
- (void)setSearching:(BOOL)searching
{
// this changes the view of the search button to a wait indicator while the search is     perfomed
// In this case
    _searching = searching;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(searching) {
            self.searchButton.enabled = NO;
            [self.searchButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
        } else {
            self.searchButton.enabled = YES;
            [self.searchButton setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        }
    });
}
// based on info from the iTunes affiliates docs
// http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html
// this assume a search button to start the search. 
- (IBAction)searchButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSString* artistTerm = self.artistField.text;  //the artist text.
    NSString* songTerm = self.songField.text;      //the song text 
    // they both need to be non-zero for this to work right.
    if(artistTerm.length > 0 && songTerm.length > 0) {

        // this creates the base of the Link Maker url call.

        NSString* baseURLString = @"https://itunes.apple.com/search";
        NSString* searchTerm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", artistTerm, songTerm];
        NSString* searchUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?media=music&entity=song&term=%@&artistTerm=%@&songTerm=%@", baseURLString, searchTerm, artistTerm, songTerm];

        // must change spaces to +
        searchUrlString = [searchUrlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

        //make it a URL
        searchUrlString = [searchUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL* searchUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:searchUrlString];
        NSLog(@"searchUrl: %@", searchUrl);

        // start the Link Maker search
        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:searchUrl];
        self.searching = YES;
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:self.operationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error) {

            // we got an answer, now find the data.
            self.searching = NO;
            if(error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            } else {
                NSError* jsonError = nil;
                NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
                if(jsonError != nil) {
                    // do something with the error here
                    NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", jsonError);
                } else {
                    NSArray* resultsArray = dict[@"results"];

                    // it is possible to get no results. Handle that here
                    if(resultsArray.count == 0) {
                        NSLog(@"No results returned.");
                    } else {

                        // extract the needed info to pass to the iTunes store search
                        NSDictionary* trackDict = resultsArray[0];
                        NSString* trackViewUrlString = trackDict[@"trackViewUrl"];
                        if(trackViewUrlString.length == 0) {
                            NSLog(@"No trackViewUrl");
                        } else {
                            NSURL* trackViewUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:trackViewUrlString];
                            NSLog(@"trackViewURL:%@", trackViewUrl);

                           // dispatch the call to switch to the iTunes store with the proper search url
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:trackViewUrl];
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

The XML file that comes back has a LOT of other good info you could extract here as well, including three sizes of album art, album name, cost, etc, etc.

I hope this helps someone else out. This stumped me for quite some time, and I thank a good friend of mine for making this work.

Comment: One quick note: The returned data is JSON, not XML. Otherwise, thanks for the info!

Comment: Yea, my bad, I was typing quickly and XML just flowed from the fingers. You are correct, JSON data is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You are in fact using a URL for the search. That's why iTunes opens on search. My iTunes in Mac OS X also opens in search.

Use the [Search API for iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) to search for the content you want and get the artist, album or song ids so you can generate a direct URL for that content.

Look in the [iTunes Link Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker) how to create a URL for an artist or for a specific album and compose that URL on your app.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I see I was not clear in my question. I actually meant that I want iTunes STORE to open in search (I fixed the question), so that is the behavior I expected. I have looked at the iTunes Link Maker, and I can create one by hand easily,  but I do not see how to use the lik maker from within an app (using Objective-C) where the song name and artist are dynamic, changing all the time, so I can create that link dynamically in my code. I also do not have an album name, or ID, just song and artist. I still should be able to se a list of albums. That is what is stumping me.

Comment: I will also add, that it does indeed open to search AS EXPECTED, but then I get that store cannot connect error, which I still do not understand. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I got it. The link maker you cannot use from the app (maybe if you inspect the POST requests done you can do it directly) but it actually does not generate search links.

Comment: Why not use the Search API and show the items from inside your app and then link to the store when you have the id for a specific album or song? Right now your requirement for showing the search in the iTunes Store is the problem I think as there's no advanced searching on iOS iTunes Store.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that now iOS already opens the iTunes app directly when you try to open a itunes html url.

Example, trying to do a openURL on **https://itunes.apple.com/br/album/falando-de-amor/id985523754**  already opens the iTunes app instead of the website.