# mp3 streaming application for the iPhone

Tags: web-services, ios4, uiwebview, stream, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to stream MP3 from an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893263/best-way-to-stream-mp3-from-an-iphone-app)

Hi, 
could any one give me a step by step tutorial on how to stream mp3 from the internet on the iPhone. I did found some tutorial but it seems way to complicated for me...Please help me

thanks, 
TC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the mp3 file is available on the internet it's not that difficult:

1. Open up safari
2. enter the url to the mp3 file -> the iphone will automatically launch music player and will play it

You could also host your own mp3's on an apache webserver and just stream it from their to your iphone.

Comment: Any type of code is appreciated.